# update multiple records in mysql as a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is there a way to combine these sql statement

```
UPDATE foreign_users_to_be_mentioned SET is_used = 1 WHERE id = 1
UPDATE foreign_users_to_be_mentioned SET is_used = 1 WHERE id = 2
```

into a single query ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `IN`:

```
UPDATE foreign_users_to_be_mentioned SET is_used = 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```